# noob question on arithmetic with proving identities

Tags: trigonometry

how does $$\sin^2x-\cos^2x+\cos^4x$$ simplify to $$\sin^2x\times\sin^2x=\sin^4x \,\,\,\,\ ?$$  I would appreciate how the steps are done to arrive to the final answer. Thanks!

Comment: You start with an expression, and end with an equality. How did that happen? (also, $\sin^2 x\times \sin^2 x= (\sin^2 x)^2 = \sin^4 x$ independent of any hypotheses).

Comment: Do you mean, how does $\sin^2x - \cos^2 x + \cos^4 x$ simplify to $\sin^4 x$?

Comment: yeah it was supposed to simplify to sin^4(x) sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin^2x-\cos^2x+\cos^4x=\sin^2x-\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x)=\sin^2x-\cos^2x\sin^2x$$ $$=\sin^2x(1-\cos^2x)=\sin^4x$$

Comment: Sorry for typo. I edited it. Thank You.

Comment: I took a moment to analyze what was done and it completely makes sense! Do you mind me asking how long it took you to recognize what to do with intricate problems in general?

Comment: Here we have only even powers of $\sin x$ and $\cos x.$  Also no double or half angles. Therefor only possible identity is $$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$